# I want to include any animated gif in my beamer presentation?

Tags: animation, latex, gif, beamer

Can anyone guide me on how to include any gif into the beamer, for example, animated *Thank you for the last slide?* Any MWE will do. I have included mine.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]


\usepackage{bibentry}
\title[Oral Defense]{\textbf{Affect Recognition}} 
\author[]{Presented By: Ms. ABC (11000100)\medskip\\{Supervised By: { Prof.}}}
\institute[MNIT, Jaipur] 
{ 
    
    {Department of CSE \\IIT Mumbai, India} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage 
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \Huge
    THANK YOU
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation/240247#240247